# React setInterval State not changed / updated

Tags: reactjs

Maybe I'm missing something, but I can't find a solution for that.

I have a React component and want to run some periodic background job (setInterval)
This job use some information of the components state and should also be able to change that.

My component:

```
export default function Form() {
   const [state, setState] = useState<IState>(initialState);
   useEffect(() => {
      //init component and other stuff
     
      // trigger background Task
      setInterval(backgroundJob, 10000);

   }, []);

   function backgroundJob(){
      state.xxx
   }

   function handleButtonClick(){
     state.xxx = state.xxx + 1;
     setState({
       ...state,
     });
   }   
}
```

The main problem is, the backgroundJob Function is able to access the state, but it's only the `initalState`. If the `state` is updated, (e.g. on a button click via the `handleButtonClick()` function), the next Interval tick still has old values in the `state`

Do I misunderstood some basic concept here?

Comment: Can you add sandbox of this?

Comment: I've just asked more or less the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63701210/update-multiple-times-same-state-from-asynchronous-callback
And reading:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55342406/updating-and-merging-state-object-using-react-usestate-hook
solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `backgroundJob` to you dependency list, but also you need to clear this interval when the effect is re-run:

Note that in the way your code is written this will happen every time the component renders. You can use [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) to optimize if needed.

```
useEffect(() => {
  //init component and other stuff
  // trigger background Task
  const intervalId = setInterval(backgroundJob, 10000);

  return () => clearInterval(intervalId)

}, [backgroundJob]);
```

In not doing so, the `backgroundJob` you are running is the one from the first render which only "see"s (via its closure) the initial state (AKA [Stale Closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/))

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't solve my problem well. My state is changing quite often, so this solution will often clear the interval and restart it again. So if my state changes every second, the background job is never executed :-(

Comment: You could use `useCallback` to depend only on specific parts of your state, or `useRef` for often changing values